# Using trig to integrate $x^2/\sqrt{16-x^2}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate:   $\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\ dx$

My try was to convert $x$ to $4\sin(u)$ and $dx$ to $4\cos(u)du$, but I'm not sure. Thanks.

Comment: That should work, what went wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You end up integrating a constant times $\sin^2 u$. One common way of handling that integral is to use the identity $\cos(2u)=1-2\sin^2 u$.

Comment: Formally:
$$
\int_{x} \frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{16 - x^{2}}} = \int_{x=4\sin u}\frac{16 \sin^{2}u}{4\cos u}\cdot 4\cos u = 16\int_{u}\sin^{2}u;
$$
$$
\sin^{2}u = \frac{1- \cos 2u}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, let $x=4\sin u\implies dx=4\cos u$

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\ dx&=\int \frac{16\sin^2u}{\sqrt{16-16\sin^2u}}(4\cos u\ du)\\\\
&=\int \frac{16\sin^2u}{\cos u}(4\cos u\ du)\\\\
&=\int \sin^2 u\ du\\\\
&=\int \frac{1-\cos (2u)}{2}\ du\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int \ du-\frac{1}{2}\int \cos (2u)\ du\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int \ du-\frac{1}{4}\int \cos (2u)\ d(2u)
\end{align}$$